# Sort Array by contains specific char count

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array and I want to sort this array by its element' specific character count.

```
var myNewArray = myArray.ToList().Sort(u => u.Name.Split(' ').Length);
```

but this does not work at all.

How can I provide the LINQ code for this problem ?

myArray[0]  = "word1 word2"
myArray[1]  = "word1"
myArray[2]  = "word3 word2 word2 word2"

when Apply sort my array element order must be like
myArray[2],myArray[0],myArray[1]

Comment: `element' specific character count.` you don't count the number of characters but the number of words... Do you?

Comment: User OrderBy, not Sort.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: This shouldn't compile, `Sort` will order the list in place, May be you are looking for `OrderBy`

Comment: @Thomas yes, in other words in sentences array, sentence which have more words must be top of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
var myNewArray = myArray.OrderByDescending(u => u.Name.Split(' ').Length).ToList();
```

To count the number of words

Comment: Yeap this is first the answer

Comment: ``OrderByDescending`` as OP needs greater count first

Comment: @EhsanSajjad true, I've changed

Answer (score 1):

User `OrderByDescending` instead

```
var myNewArray = myArray.OrderByDescending(u => u.Name.Split(' ').Length).ToList();
```

This will save you producing two in-memory lists as well

Comment: Nop, the OP wants the number of words

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not compile [`List.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas(v=vs.110).aspx) modifies the current list in place, it doesn't return a new collection.

Having said that, you need `Enumerable.OrderByDescending`

> sentence which have more words must be top of the array

Since you have an `Array` to begin with you can simply do:

```
var myNewArray = myArray.OrderByDescending(u => u.Name.Split(' ').Length).ToArray();
```

Make sure to include `using System.Linq;`

*(Remove `ToArray` if you only need an `IEnumerable<T>`)*